# Setting div max height doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: relative; overflow: visible; width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="surface">
    <div style="width: 300px; max-height: 2px; height: 2px; position: absolute; left: 36.165px; top: 0.8957px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
    <div style="width: 1px; height: 200px; position: absolute; left: 30.165px; top: 47.8957px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are basically two `div`s: one "horizontal" (height 2px) and one "vertical" (height 2px).

When I view the page on firefox:

[image]

while on IE (8) something weired happens:

[image]

the top DIV is not 2px high.

Any idea why is that so ?

Comment: Here is a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqps5/1/). IE9 is fine.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I tried to set up a jsfiddle my self and it was fine even in IE 8, that why i had to make the printscreen. Can you please try to put my code in a .html and see if you have this wiered behavious in your IE as well ? (not using jsfiddle).

Comment: so does IE7 ... maybe you just need to add `display: block`

Comment: @JFK can you please put that in a HTML file and see if you have the problem ?

Comment: works fine in a regular html file, check you have a proper `DOCTYPE`

Comment: @JFK i have no `DOCTYPE`, actually all my HTML is the code I posted.

Comment: well, add a `DOCTYPE` otherwise quirks mode will produce unexpected format and results

Comment: people is posting answers based on my comments LOL ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your possible solutions :

1). Add `display: block` to your style

2). check you have a proper `DOCTYPE` otherwise (IE) quirks mode will produce unexpected format and results. [Check this article for reference](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem appears to stem from ie's `quirks mode` mode.

It occurs when there is no doctype declaration. Max height, among other things (including the box model) acts as if it were ie5. A simple solution is to add a doctype declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

Answer (score 3):

IE7, 8 and 9 works fine here.

You dont really need the `max-height`, but setting a `display: block` and/or `line-height: 2px` instead could be a solution.

Comment: yep but it doesn't explain why I was able to see that in jsfiddle but not in my plain HTML, @Tyzoid solution applies for all my code

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this will be IE addding some "helpful" settings in quirks mode that pushes the height of a container to the minimum text height. Try setting `line-height: 2px;` for IE8 and lower (conditional comments, perhaps?) and that should sort it.

Comment: yep but it doesn't explain why I was able to see that in jsfiddle but not in my plain HTML, @Tyzoid solution applies for all my code

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a

> min-height

setting that Override the other settings